# Get notification when lync conference starts

Tags: lync, ucma, conference

Is there any way I can be notified when a new conference starts in a lync server?
I'm thinking of using a UCMA application to accomplish that, but not sure this can be done.

My main goal is to be notified when any conference starts, so I can get some info about the user initiating it and do some processing.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is a conference table in the rtc database which you can use to find conferences to monitor.  The UCMA application could then join the conference (using ConferenceSession.BeginJoin()) and watch for participants as they join via the ParticipantEndpointAttendanceChanged event.